# Mount docker logical volume

Tags: linux, docker, amazon-ecs, docker-volume, lvm

I'm trying to access to a logical volume where previously was used by docker. This is the result of various command:

lsblk

```
NAME                          MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1                       259:2    0  80G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1                   259:3    0  80G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p128                 259:4    0   1M  0 part
nvme1n1                       259:0    0  80G  0 disk
└─nvme1n1p1                   259:1    0  80G  0 part
  ├─docker-docker--pool_tdata 253:1    0  79G  0 lvm
  │ └─docker-docker--pool     253:2    0  79G  0 lvm
  └─docker-docker--pool_tmeta 253:0    0  84M  0 lvm
    └─docker-docker--pool     253:2    0  79G  0 lvm
```

fdisk

```
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 85.9 GB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00029c01

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/nvme1n1p1            2048   167772159    83885056   8e  Linux LVM
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 85.9 GB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: 358A5F86-3BCA-4FB2-8C00-722B915A71AB


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         4096    167772126     80G  Linux filesyste Linux
128         2048         4095      1M  BIOS boot       BIOS Boot Partition
```

lvdisplay

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                docker-pool
  VG Name                docker
  LV UUID                piD2Wx-aDjf-CkpN-b4s4-YXWE-6ERm-GWTcOz
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ip-172-31-39-159, 2020-02-16 09:18:57 +0000
  LV Pool metadata       docker-pool_tmeta
  LV Pool data           docker-pool_tdata
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                79.03 GiB
  Allocated pool data    80.07%
  Allocated metadata     31.58%
  Current LE             20232
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2
```

But when I try to mount the volume `docker-docker--pool_tdata` I get the following error:

```
mount  /dev/mapper/docker-docker--pool_tdata /mnt/test
mount: /dev/mapper/docker-docker--pool_tdata is already mounted or /mnt/test busy
```

I've also tried to reboot the machine, to uninstall docker and to see if there is file opened on that volume using `lsof`

Do you have any clue about how can I mount that volume? 
Thanks

Comment: That looks like an LVM devicemapper tree from an old version of Docker.  Even if you could mount the volume, the image and container contents there won't be stored in a way that's easy to extract.

Comment: The purpose of this was just try to understand why `docker info` and `docker system df` show different space used. several question have been asked, but with no answer so far. https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-system-df-doesnt-add-up-to-docker-info-data-space/60238   https://forums.docker.com/t/questions-about-the-docker-storage-usage/60269

Comment: Did you try mounting it to another directory? The output suggests that `/mnt/test` might be busy.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling docker does not really help as `purge` and `autoremove` only delete the installed packages and not the images, containers, volumes and config files.

To delete those you have to delete a bunch of directories contained in `etc`, `var/lib`, `bin` and`var/run`

1. Clean up the env

try running `docker system prune -a` to remove unused containers, images etc
remove the volume with `docker volume rm {volumeID}`
create the volume again `docker volume create docker-docker--pool_tdata`

2. Kill the process

run `lsof +D /mnt/test` or `cat ../docker/../tasks`
this should display the PIDs of alive tasks.

Kill the task with `kill -9 {PID}`